# Simple jQuery show/hide table

Tags: jquery

I have this simple JQuery function to hide or show a table. the show/hide works but the image (plus/minus) is not changing.

The table is like this:

```
     <span id="collapsible">These are some
     new titles. 
    <table id="data">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="3">2008</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>As You Like It</td>
    <td>Comedy</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><th colspan="3">2007</th><tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Henry IV, Part I</td>
    <td>History</td>
    <td>1596</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunit Joshi</td>
    <td>History</td>
    <td>2010</td>
  </tr>
</table>

 </span>
```

The jQuery function is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var collapseIcon = 'images/minus.png';

var collapseText = 'Collapse this section';

var expandIcon = 'images/plus.png';

var expandText = 'Expand this section';

var $subHead = $('#collapsible');
$subHead.prepend('<img src="' + expandIcon + '" alt="' + expandText + '" class="clickable" />')

$subHead.click(function(){
    $('#data').toggle();
    ($('#data').is(':hidden')) ? $(this).attr('src', expandIcon) : $(this).attr('src', collapseIcon);
    return false;
});

$subHead.css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .click();
```

});

Any thoughts what might be wrong here. The image stays at the initial '+' state.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has several validation errors in it. This can cause JavaScript to break or produce unexpected results. Run the HTML through the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix those errors. If it still won't work from there edit your question with the valid HTML and I will help further.

---

OP already answered his question but since I have the code here I will post mine as well.

Valid HTML:

```
<div id="collapsible">These are some new titles. 
   <table id="data">
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">2008</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>As You Like It</td>
         <td>Comedy</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">2007</th>
         <td>Henry IV, Part I</td>
         <td>Hist=ry</td>
         <td>1596</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Sunit Joshi</td>
         <td>History</td>
         <td>2010</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Fixed Javascript:

```
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    var collapseIcon = 'images/minus.png';

    var collapseText = 'Collapse this section';

    var expandIcon = 'images/plus.png';

    var expandText = 'Expand this section';

    var $subHead = $('#collapsible');
    $subHead.prepend('<img src="' + expandIcon + '" alt="' + expandText + '" class="clickable" id="expandImage" />')

    $subHead.click(function(){
        $('#data').toggle();
        ($('#data').is(':hidden')) ? $("#expandImage").attr('src', expandIcon).attr('alt', expandText) : $("#expandImage").attr('src', collapseIcon).attr('alt', collapseText);
        console.log($(this).attr('src'));
        return false;
    });

    $subHead.css('cursor', 'pointer').click();

});
//-->
```

I also added the alt attr. to the image since I am assume you wanted that as well.

Comment: I have #collapsible so that I can Click on the span element.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the id on the span.

Comment: Thanks. Can you reproduce it ? It's so simple but does not work. Driving me nuts..!!

Comment: I have updated my answer, fix those errors first and it may work.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by giving an id to the image tag. Here's the update:

...previous code

```
var $subHead = $('#collapsible');
$subHead.prepend('<img id="imgpointer" src="' + expandIcon + '" class="clickable" />')

$subHead.click(function(){
    $('table#data').toggle();
    ($('table#data').is(':hidden')) 
        ? $('img#imgpointer').attr('src', expandIcon) 
        : $('img#imgpointer').attr('src', collapseIcon);
    return false;
});
```

...rest of code.
I'll check the HTML validation errors as MitMaro mentioned.

thanks
Sunit

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this answer isn't fix for bug in your code but I'd like to post slightly more generic and probably a better solution considering it uses some of the best practices.

Below example works with any number of levels in hierarchy and including complex scenarios were you want to give special treatment to parent with only one child. It also uses Font Awesome to get better glyph (especially useful if you are using Bootstrap). Also instead of using jquery toggle on arbitrary element, you can checkbox element which has built-in toggle state.

So let's start out by your table markup. First you would put +/- symbols in one of the table cells like this:

```
<tr><td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="parent1" class="txRowExpanderControl" checked>
    <label class="txRowExpanderControlLabel" for="parent1">
        <i class="rowsExpandIcon"></i>&nbsp;
    </label>{{title}}
</td></tr>
```

The rows that should be collapsed/expanded should be marked with data- attribute like this.

```
<tr data-expanderid="parent1">...</tr>
<tr data-expanderid="parent1">...</tr>
```

Next, your related CSS classes would look like this (note that I'm using LESS but if you are not then you can directly embed fa* classes in your markup):

```
.txRowExpanderControl {
    display:none;   //don't show checkbox
}
.txRowExpanderControlLabel {
    cursor: pointer;    //cursor same as link
}

.rowsExpandIcon:extend(.fa all):extend(.fa-plus-square-o all) {
}
.rowsCollapseIcon:extend(.fa all):extend(.fa-minus-square-o all) {
}

.txRowVisible {
    display:table-row;
}
.txRowCollapsed {
    display:none;
}
```

Finally, your JavaScript would look like this. Note that I'm using delegated events which are better than direct binding and also instead of jQuery toggle I'm using explicit on/off so things are easily debuggable.

```
$("#myTable").delegate(".txRowExpanderControl", "click", function () {   
    var currentState = $(this).prop("checked");
    var expanderId = $(this).attr("id");
    var childRows = $(this).closest("tr").nextAll("tr[data-expanderid=\"" + expanderId + "\"]");
    var expanderIcon = $(this).next("label[for=\"" + expanderId + "\"]").children("i");

    if (currentState) {
        childRows.attr("class", "txRowCollapsed");
        expanderIcon.attr("class", "rowsExpandIcon");
    }
    else {
        childRows.attr("class", "txRowVisible");
        expanderIcon.attr("class", "rowsCollapseIcon");
    }
});
```